# LINQ to SQL query help (string contains any string in string array)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda

I've been tearing my hair out with this one. I've got an array of search terms and I'm trying to do a LINQ to SQL query to search field values against each item in the array.

I got this far..

```
var searchResults = 
    from x in SDC.Staff_Persons
    where staffTermArray.Any(pinq => x.Forename.Contains(pinq))
        || staffTermArray.Any(pinq => x.Surname.Contains(pinq))
        || staffTermArray.Any(pinq => x.Known_as.Contains(pinq))
    orderby x.Surname
    select x;
```

... but then got

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ
>   to SQL implementation of query
>   operators except the Contains()
>   operator

... and now I'm stuck.

If anyone can help I'd be very grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Rob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the easiest solution, but this will work:

```
var filter = CreateFilter(staffTermArray);

var searchResults = 
    from person in SDC.Staff_Persons.Where(filter)
    orderby person.Surname
    select person;



private static Expression<Func<Staff_Person, bool>> CreateFilter(
    string[] staffTermArray)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Staff_Person>();

    foreach (var staffTerm in staffTermArray)
    {
       // We need to make a local copy because of C# weirdness.
       var ping = staffTerm;

       predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Forename.Contains(ping));
       predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Surname.Contains(ping));
       predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Known_as.Contains(ping));
    }

    return predicate;
}
```

You will need the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) for this to work.

Comment: Wow - I'd come across the term 'predicate builder' while searching for the solution but nobody's explained it in such simple terms! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to do the filtering on the client rather than in SQL. You can force the `where` to be evaluated on the client by calling `AsEnumerable()`. However, this means that every row of the table is loaded into memory before being tested for a match, so it may be unacceptably inefficient if your search matches only a small number of results from a large table.

```
var allPersons = 
    from x in SDC.Staff_Persons
    orderby x.Surname
    select x;

var searchResults = 
    from x in allPersons.AsEnumerable()
    where staffTermArray.Any(pinq => x.Forename.Contains(pinq))
        || staffTermArray.Any(pinq => x.Surname.Contains(pinq))
        || staffTermArray.Any(pinq => x.Known_as.Contains(pinq))
    select x;
```

Comment: Yeah i did have that thought, and actually it's only 1200 records so that wouldn't be too bad. But my load-time OCD is stopping me... :)

Comment: On issue can be that this works great on a small test database, but once the client gets to larger data it will fail gloriously.  I ran into a case where we were looking through a log table with 4.8 million lines and loading it all and then filtering was just not an option.